# Calling Microsoft CRM 2011 On-premise web service with CXF

Tags: java, dynamics-crm-2011, cxf, kerberos, ws-security

I am attempting to integrate a Java application with our on-premise Microsoft CRM 2011 using its native web-services.

My offset is the description in [this blog post](http://groovyjava-tom.blogspot.dk/2012/01/cxf-and-ms-crm-2011.html) and my code does not differ much, but I am now stuck with a `org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The signature or decryption was invalid`

I am able to retrieve both TGT and service ticket from Active Directory and gets a Krb5Context created before the web-service is called and CXF fails on the response - which appears to be an error, but as it cannot be decrypted, it is not helpful in diagnosing the problem. (The full stack-trace and SOAP-response is included below.)

I am using CXF version 2.7.11, although I have also tried a number of other versions to see if that made any difference.

My biggest concern is probably, whether the Kerberos configuration is correct, as it is hard to find good documentation of the requirements for this.

My code:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "crm-integration/src/main/resources/login.conf");
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "crm-integration/src/main/resources/krb5.conf");

OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService(new URL("http://192.168.20.88/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?singleWsdl"));
IOrganizationService port = service.getPort(IOrganizationService.class);

Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
Bus bus = ((EndpointImpl) client.getEndpoint()).getBus();
bus.getProperties().put("soap.no.validate.parts", true);
PolicyInterceptorProviderRegistry policyInterceptorProviderRegistry = bus.getExtension(PolicyInterceptorProviderRegistry.class);
policyInterceptorProviderRegistry.register(new XRMAuthPolicyProvider());

HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = http.getClient();
httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);

//Enable logging - remove when solution is working
System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());

// Kerberos service provider name, e.g. RestrictedKrbHost/<computer-name>
String spn = "RestrictedKrbHost/CRM.CRMTEST.LOCAL"; //ServicePrincipalName for CRM-server
// Kerberos JAAS client as configured in login.conf
String jaasClient = "spnego-client";
// Active Directory username and password
CallbackHandler callbackHandler = new NamePasswordCallbackHandler(username, password);

client.getRequestContext().put("ws-security.kerberos.jaas.context", jaasClient);
client.getRequestContext().put("ws-security.kerberos.spn", spn);
client.getRequestContext().put("ws-security.callback-handler", callbackHandler);
client.getRequestContext().put("ws-security.spnego.client.action", new XRMSpnegoClientAction());

OrganizationRequest request = new OrganizationRequest();
request.setRequestName("WhoAmI");
port.execute(request);
```

My `login.conf`:

```
spnego-client {
 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required client=TRUE useTicketCache=true;
};
```

And my `krb5.conf`:

```
[libdefaults]
 default_realm = CRMTEST.LOCAL
 default_tkt_enctypes = aes128-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1
 default_tgs_enctypes = aes128-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1
 permitted_enctypes   = aes128-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1

[realms]
 CRMTEST.LOCAL = {
 kdc = 192.168.1.86
 default_domain = crmtest
}

[domain_realm]
 crmtest = CRMTEST.LOCAL
```

**Stack-trace:**

```
[main] WARN org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services}OrganizationService#{http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services}RetrieveMultiple has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: The signature or decryption was invalid
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.createSoapFault(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:852)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:327)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:845)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1624)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1513)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1318)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:223)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:632)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.retrieveMultiple(Unknown Source)
    at integration.crm.Main.main(Main.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The signature or decryption was invalid
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.verifyXMLSignature(SignatureProcessor.java:451)
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.handleToken(SignatureProcessor.java:231)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:396)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:270)
    ... 26 more
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: The signature or decryption was invalid
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.retrieveMultiple(Unknown Source)
    at integration.crm.Main.main(Main.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The signature or decryption was invalid
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.verifyXMLSignature(SignatureProcessor.java:451)
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.handleToken(SignatureProcessor.java:231)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:396)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:270)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:845)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1624)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1513)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1318)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:223)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:632)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
    ... 7 more
```

**SOAP-response:**

```
[main] INFO     [main] INFO org.apache.cxf.services.OrganizationService.CustomBinding_IOrganizationService.IOrganizationService - Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 1
Response-Code: 500
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Headers: {Cache-Control=[private], Content-Length=[10199], content-type=[application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8], Date=[Thu, 08 May 2014 14:58:59 GMT], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/7.5], Set-Cookie=[ReqClientId=a888fa05-b125-41b1-a9f6-06e92e435c85; expires=Thu, 08-May-2064 14:58:59 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly], X-AspNet-Version=[4.0.30319], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET]}
Payload: 
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
            xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_4">
            http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/RetrieveMultipleOrganizationServiceFaultFault
        </a:Action>
        <a:RelatesTo u:Id="_5">urn:uuid:d83d2351-fd16-45c2-8190-62a54d9ee3f3</a:RelatesTo>
        <ActivityId CorrelationId="f6a77d88-163d-4d95-9b65-dc072d787bf4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">
            00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
        </ActivityId>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-ce5d195c-8146-4470-b58a-c0bc8d6cc591-74">
                <u:Created>2014-05-08T14:58:59.549Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2014-05-08T15:03:59.549Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <c:DerivedKeyToken u:Id="_0" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
                <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                    <o:Reference URI="urn:uuid:dceef0c2-c68c-49a4-b42c-4e8a26a78e5d" ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct"/>
                </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                <c:Offset>0</c:Offset>
                <c:Length>24</c:Length>
                <c:Nonce>Mjov1pR34KbNLmxQScRTDA==</c:Nonce>
            </c:DerivedKeyToken>
            <c:DerivedKeyToken u:Id="_1" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
                <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                    <o:Reference URI="urn:uuid:dceef0c2-c68c-49a4-b42c-4e8a26a78e5d" ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct"/>
                </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                <c:Nonce>Rblzft4LnWG8FZRZQhxgRQ==</c:Nonce>
            </c:DerivedKeyToken>
            <e:ReferenceList xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <e:DataReference URI="#_3"/>
                <e:DataReference URI="#_6"/>
            </e:ReferenceList>
            <e:EncryptedData Id="_6" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
                <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/dk" URI="#_1"/>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
                <e:CipherData>
                    <e:CipherValue>
                        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
                    </e:CipherValue>
                </e:CipherData>
            </e:EncryptedData>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body u:Id="_2">
        <e:EncryptedData Id="_3" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                    <o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/dk" URI="#_1"/>
                </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
            <e:CipherData>
                <e:CipherValue>
                    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
                </e:CipherValue>
            </e:CipherData>
        </e:EncryptedData>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: I know you tried multiple versions of CXF, but maybe trying 2.1.3 or older will reveal the error message. There is a report in CXF mailing list that claims that similar issues popped up after an upgrade from 2.1.3 http://osdir.com/ml/users-cxf-apache/2009-09/msg00494.html

Comment: You may be interested in http://groovyjava-tom.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/cxf-and-ms-crm-2011.html, and its comments.  The error you report is also mentioned there.

Comment: @MarnixKlooster - yeah - that is the blog post I link in the second paragraph of the question. ;)

Comment: @tveon I'm sorry, I missed that. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to all the documentations over On-premise web service with CXF, you have this error:

```
The signature or decryption was invalid
```

Because you are receiving an xml with the body containing a fault message.

If you look more closely you can see that it indeed contains a fault:

```
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_4">               
 http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/RetrieveMultipleOrganizationServiceFaultFault      
</a:Action>
```

I think this is a bug that is needed to be addressed.

Workaround: when an exception like this appears catch it and otput it as a fault message response from the web-service.

Comment: Yeah, I also worry that this is bug. :\ Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any "fault message response from the web-service". As you can see in the SOAP-response, everything is encrypted, and the handling fails during signature validation or decryption. :(

Comment: yes but the encrypted message is in reality a fault message?

Comment: if you look more closely you can see that it indeed contains a fault:  <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_4">
            http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/RetrieveMultipleOrganizationServiceFaultFault
        </a:Action>

Comment: Yes - as mentioned in the question, the response is an error (or "fault" to use the correct word), so how am I supposed to use this information to get closer to solving the problem?

Comment: the body has info, and everything is fine. you have the key and the data. you need to decipher the data by the key that's it. and handle the exception in the application and never show it to the user as it is a bug, get it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Axis2 if you can since NTLM/Kerberos issues are already solved in that framework.Reference

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dynamics-coe/archive/2013/09/21/integrating-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-online-with-java-and-other-non-net-clients.aspx

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602979(v=crm.5).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602979%28v=crm.5%29.aspx)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328497(v=crm.5).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328497%28v=crm.5%29.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327986.aspx

Also go thru this URL

https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Integrating-Java-web-application-CRM-21231.S.122850559

Comment: Thanks for your input, but it does not address my question. The sources you link, does either not relate to the On-Premise version of Dynamics CRM or are simply general guidelines/information about how an integration could be made.